# Get detailed error for exception in SignalR Core Hub method execution

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

When I call Hub method I get frame response:

> {"invocationId":"1","type":3,"error":"An error occurred while updating
>   the entries. See the inner exception for details."}

How can I get detailed error report (row and file where error occurred) without manually debugging and using step over and check where the code raise exception.

On net I found plenty codes where `EnableDetailedErrors` is used

```
services.AddSignalR(options => 
        {
            options.Hubs.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });
```

but options (at least in version 1.0.0-alpha2-final) does not have property Hubs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently the option to enable detailed errors is not implemented. There is [an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/254) tracking this. My recommendation would be to turn on logging on the server side - the original exception will be logged there.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Just ran into this, seems like it still does not work

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing

Answer (score 13):

This is what you need to do in core (not sure the exact version this was added):

```
        // signalR
        services.AddSignalR(options =>
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
                options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            }
        });
```

It goes without saying that the reason this is disabled by default in production is for security reasons. So be careful not to expose things you may not wish 'hackers' to see in any of the exceptions you may throw.

Implementing the above setting will reveal a more detailed message in the browser console, whcih you can also see in the websocket debugging tab:

[image]

---

Quick tip:

I've set up SignalR twice now on ASPNetCore and I think I've made the same mistake both times:

```
// from typescript client arguments are passed like this
this.hubConnection.invoke('SendMessage', 'simon', 'hello');

// not like this
this.hubConnection.invoke('SendMessage', ['simon', 'hello']);
```

Also `invoke` will wait for a response, while `send` does not. So you may not see errors using `send`.

Comment: This should be the right answer as @Pawel 's answer is very outdated.

Comment: options.EnableDetailedErrors = true; is what i was looking for

Comment: Interesting behaviour observed for anybody who's interested - with this setting enabled server side, it disables the automatic reconnect retry policy configured client side (using `HubConnectionBuilder.withAutomaticReconnect()`)

Comment: @JamesLaw thanks for mentioning this. Does seem odd - but I didn't even know there was an automatic reconnect feature! Looks like it was added without me noticing.